# When Spring Framework as a whole updates its version?

Tags: spring

I was reading this article on structure of Spring: http://springtutorials.com/introduction-to-spring-modules/

From this what I understand is that Spring is basically a collection of projects, which are then a collection of sub-projects, which are then a collection of modules.

I guess modules are updated to a new version, when some new features are implemented. And project versions are updated when it uses/implements new modules.

But I wonder when/how "Spring" as a whole updates its version. I'm a bit confused because it seems each Spring project runs on its own(Has its own versions, and has its own modules to use) If each Spring project updates by itself, then how do the authors decide that the whole "Spring Framework" is up to a new version? (As now in Spring Framework 5.0 https://spring.io/ )

And also is it that the word "Spring Framework" is used in 2 places: one as a general word referring to the entire Spring ecosystem, and the other one referring an actual project that implements some of the core functionalities such as dependency injections, as seen at:  https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/